# On a extended class, can i use a getter and setter of a class that implements multiple interfaces

Tags: java, oop

I have a Java package with common code that it will be distributed on the team to work on two projects.

One project is already in progress, so i'll have to adapt existing code to work with this new package.

That package has interfaces and classes similar to the following:

```
public interface Person{
}

public interface Group{
    List<Person> getPeople();
    void setPeople(List<Person> people);
}

public abstract AbstractPerson implements Person{
}

public abstract AbstractGroup implements Group{
    List<Person> people;


    public List<Person> getPeople(){
       return this.items;
    };

    public void setPeople(List<Person> people){
       this.people=people;
    }
}

    public class Analyzer(){

        public void analyzePeople(Group group){

            List<Person> items=group.getPeople();

            ....
        }
    }
```

One project that is already in progress we have a class that will be changed like this:

```
public class Doctor extends ExistingClass implements ExistingInterface,Person {

}
```

I don't have the group class so i'm going to implement it,

```
public class CurrentGroup extends AbstractGroup(){

}
```

The ideia is to use the code the following way:

```
CurrentGroup currentGroup=new CurrentGroup();
currentGroup.setPeople(new ArrayList<Doctor>());
...

Analyzer analyzer=new Analyzer();
analyzer.analyzePeople(currentGroup);
```

I have two problems:

- This class implementation must hold a collection of Doctor;
- The collections on my current code are ArrayLists;

All of this should be working since the ArrayList implements List and Doctor implements Person, but it does not since eclipse shows the error "The method `setPeople(List<Person>)` in the type Processo is not applicable for the arguments `(ArrayList<Doctor>)`".

Is there any way to have the CurrentGroup class hold a list of Doctor as an ArrayList and still work on the method AnalizePeople from the class Analizer ?

Comment: If I understand right, you just need to return the doctor list in the override getPeople() method in your Group class. You should have this method implemented already as it's defined in the Interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all depends on the actual *contract* of the interface. You specified it as

```
public interface Group{
    List<Person> getPeople();
    void setPeople(List<Person> people);
}
```

but…is it guaranteed that the method `getPeople` returns the same list (reference) that was passed in a previous `setPeople` invocation? And is it guaranteed to be *mutable*?

If you answer both questions with true, then there is no way to do what you are trying to do. As in that case the contract implies that you can do a `group.getPeople().add(person)` with arbitrary `Group` and `Person` implementations. Setting it to a `List<Doctor>` which only accepts `Doctor` instances would violate that contract.

If the list is not required to be mutable, you can do:

```
List<Doctor> list=…;
group.setPeople(Collections.unmodifiableList(list));
```

before Java 8, you would have to use

```
group.setPeople(Collections.<Person>unmodifiableList(list));
```

This works, because the `List<Doctor>` is guaranteed to return `Person` instances when being examined but you can’t add arbitrary `Person` instances as such modification attempts are rejected at runtime.

But it implies that in order to add `Doctor` instances, you have to keep a reference to the original `List<Doctor>` somewhere.

It would be entirely different, if `Group`s were supposed to hold `Person`s but not to keep the reference to a `List` instance provided by the caller of `setPeople`. Then, the generic signature could get relaxed like this:

```
interface Group {
    List<Person> getPeople();
    void setPeople(List<? extends Person> people);
}
class AbstractGroup implements Group {
    final ArrayList<Person> people=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Person> getPeople() {
      return people; // or Collections.unmodifiableList(people)
    }

    public void setPeople(List<? extends Person> people) {
      this.people.clear();
      this.people.addAll(people);
    }
}
```

Then, you could simply say

```
List<Doctor> list=…;
group.setPeople(list);
```

to initialize the group’s people to your doctors, however, you don’t have a guaranty that it stays a homogeneous group of doctors (unless it’s a purely local object that you don’t hand out to code which could modify it).

There’s also the option of making `Group` a generic class having a type parameter specifying its member type, but if you have to deal with already existing code, that might turn out to be an impossible change.

Comment: The List<? extends Person> ended up solving my problem. This way i can have a list of classes that extend person just like i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the doctor to the list represented by `getPeople()`, then it'll work transparently, since it implements `Person`.

BTW: your method should be called `analizePeople` to keep with Java method naming conventions.

Comment: I clarified (i think) the post and added some new details.

Answer (score 0):

this wont' work:

```
public void AnalizePeople(Group group){
    List<Person> items=group.getPeople();
```

Because Group doesn't define `getPeople`.

This will be confusing:

```
public class Group extends AbstractGroup(){
```

since there already is an interface called `Group`.

"Is there any way to have the group class hold a list of Doctor and still work on the method AnalizePeople from the class Analizer ?"

AnalizePeople (sic) is in the class Analizer. Your new class Group currently has no relation to Analizer so it won't be able to call AnalizePeople().

Please format your code properly by indenting with at least 4 spaces. Also, method names should start with a lower case character. And 'analyze' should be spelled with a 'y' not an 'i'.

It is completely unclear what you are trying to achieve exactly and what you are asking currently is utter gibberish. Please clarify.

Comment: Edited. Do you understand now ? If not please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I understand now. You really made a mess (-:. See Holger's answer, it covers just about everything I believe.